# how to fetch top distinct data in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table named `employee_salary`, with three columns: `empsal_id`, `empsal_name` and `empsal_sal`. The data is as follows:

```
empsal_id   empsal_name   empsal_sal

1           dilip         14000
2           santosh       20000
3           amit          32000
4           dilip         22000
5           amit          38000
6           santosh       25000
7           dilip         30000
```

The `empsal_id` is an Identity column with a Seed and an Increment of 1, and is the Primary Key. I want to return the name and current salary of each employee. Salary can decrease as well as increase, so current does not necessarily mean highest.

So I need the following output:

```
empname     emp_sal
dilip       30000
amit        38000
santosh     25000
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server, and I have to do this in a single query.

Comment: Can a salary ever go down?  And if so, do you have any other fields in that table?

Comment: Why is dilip 32000 and not 3000? Whats the name of the column they are sorted on? Is there a pk on the table?

Comment: I don't understand by "dilip  32000 and not 3000"

Comment: how do you know which salary is the most recent?

Comment: there is a unique id for each row which always increases when new record inserted with each row, that is recid, may it be use to fetch data

Comment: Is empid an int with identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will return each employee, along with their highest salary:

```
    SELECT
        empsal_name, MAX(empsal_sal)
    FROM
        employee
    GROUP BY
        empsal_name
```

This query will return each employee, along with their current salary (i.e. the salary with the highest `empsal_id`:

```
    SELECT
        empsal_name, empsal_sal
    FROM
        employee e1
    WHERE
        empsal_id =
            (SELECT MAX(empsal_id)
             FROM employee e2
             WHERE e1.empsal_name=e2.empsal_name)
```

Personally, I think you would be better off using an effective date column (e.g. `empsal_effectivedate`) to determine which record is the most current, so this query will return each employee, along with their current salary (i.e. the salary with the most recent `empsal_effectivedate`), assuming there is an `empsal_effectivedate` field:

```
    SELECT
        empsal_name, empsal_sal
    FROM
        employee e1
    WHERE
        empsal_effectivedate =
            (SELECT MAX(empsal_effectivedate)
             FROM employee e2
             WHERE e1.empsal_name=e2.empsal_name)
```

Comment: it is not sure that salary will be increase may be it will decrease and I have to fetch current data

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT empname, MAX(emp_sal) 
FROM   employee
GROUP BY  empname
```

UPDATED:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmpA.empname, 
                EmpA.emp_sal
FROM Employee AS EmpA 
     INNER JOIN ( SELECT  EmpName, MAX(recID) AS recid 
                  FROM Employee 
                  GROUP BY EmpName
                ) AS EmpB ON EmpA.recid = EmpB.recid;
```

Comment: it is not sure that salary will be increase may be it will decrease and I have to fetch current data

Comment: Well then you'll need a date field.

Comment: what is your basis to fetch the current data?

Comment: there is a unique id for each row which always increases when new record inserted with each row, that is recid, may it be use to fetch data

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is also an ID in the table and also assuming that the larger this ID is the most recent the salary is for that employee you can do

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    e.empname,
    (SELECT TOP 1 
        emp_sal 
    FROM 
        employee s
    WHERE 
        s.empname = e.empname 
    ORDER BY 
        recid DESC) AS emp_sal
FROM
    employee e
```

(*also assuming that `empname` is unique for an employee*)

---

***because of the many assumptions though*** : you should probably post all the columns of the table and what they mean ..

Comment: updated answer to use the `recid` name suggested in the comments of the question..

Comment: @user571616 , with ***unique*** i mean that there are no two employees named dilip. All `dilip` names refer to the same person..

Answer (score 0):

You need a date field to determine the latest inserted row . In case if the table is linked to some other table which has date column in it .Then its pretty easy to fetch the current data . 
For Example

```
    Employee Table 
    {
    EmpName varchar(30) PK,
    EmpAddress varchar(255) ,
    Company varchar(30),
    CurrentTimeStamp Datetime
    }

    Salary Table 
    {
    EmpName varchar(30) FK,
    EmpSalary int
    }
```

To get the Latest record use the CTE function

```
    With LatestSal(EmpName ,EmpSalary)
    AS
    (
    Select row_number() over (PARTITION BY b.[EmpName], order by CurrentTimestamp DESC) as seq
    b.EmpName,b.EmpSalary
    From Employee as a,
    Salary as b
    on a.[EmpName]=b.[EmpName]
    ) 
    Select EmpName,EmpSalary 
    from LatestSal
    where seq=1
```